# jQuery show div for several minutes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Hello I have multiple divs which are separated by different ids and i have a dive named as show_ads now i want to show this ad div on current active div after 3 minutes for once for just 10 seconds to show my ad and this automatically closes that show_ads div

here is my code:

```
<div id="main_1">
//content here for 1
</div>

<div id="main_2">
//content here for 2
</div>

<div id="main_3">
//content here for 3
</div>

<div id="main_4">
// content here for 4
</div>



<div id="show_ads">
// ad code here
</div>
```

e.g. if someone is clicked on div main_2 then is means main_2 div is currently activated now after 3 minutes show_ad div will appear just for once only for 10 seconds and automatically close

then again the same user clicks on main_3 it the same process will activated again

Comment: What code have you got? Where are you getting stuck?

Comment: I am totally stuck on this scenario and don't know where to start with it :(

Comment: Hint: use a combination of the `.click()`, `.append()`, `.stop()`, `.delay()`, `.show()` and `.hide()` methods. You don't need to use `setTimeout()` directly - although it would be good to learn how it works.

Comment: yes these are good but I am very new to jquery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this will get you started: http://jsfiddle.net/gd217fgo/

Html:

```
<div id="main_1" >
    div 1
</div>

<div id="show">
    ad here
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
$(function() {
    $("#show").hide();
    $("#main_1").click( function(){
        setTimeout(function(){
                $("#show").show();
            setTimeout(function() {
        $("#show").hide()
    }, 5000);
        }, 3000);
    });
});
```

Comment: yes the same thing but with multiple divs with same ids  like main_1, main_2, main_3 and location of **show** div will be center of active div

Comment: Are you looking for someone to write the code for you?

Comment: no no i just want some help but fortunately i am new to jquery thats why asking stupid question

Comment: just help me once that if i have 10 div but their prefix is same i.e. main_01 how can i set this for all

Comment: `$("#show").delay(3000).show(1).delay(5000).hide(1)` does the same thing rather more simply. (Still uses `setTimeout()` under the covers, of course.) http://jsfiddle.net/gd217fgo/1/

Answer (score 0):

Your html:

```
<div id="main_1">
    <div class="content">
    <h1>Lorem ipsum</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin nibh nisi, scelerisque eget ultrices ut, euismod id justo. Vivamus vitae nibh pellentesque, consequat metus ut, rhoncus enim. Curabitur blandit sem sed diam pretium, nec mattis erat hendrerit. Maecenas a magna erat. Morbi in turpis eget orci suscipit dignissim. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Mauris turpis augue, sollicitudin at odio non, fermentum imperdiet augue. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Maecenas rutrum ante ipsum, sit amet euismod risus dapibus ut. Praesent eget magna vel nisi vehicula vestibulum. Quisque nec nunc pulvinar, blandit magna at, hendrerit nibh. Sed mattis massa a massa lacinia venenatis. Donec non erat justo.</p>
</div>
    <div class="read-more"><a onClick="$().readMore();">Read more</a></div>
</div>
<div id="main_2">
//content here for 2
</div>

<div id="main_3">
//content here for 3
</div>

<div id="show_ads">
    <center>Ads here</center>
</div>
```

Your css:

```
#main_1 {
    background-color: #F1F1F1;
}
.content {
    width: 500px;
    height: 200px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.read-more a {
    cursor: pointer;
    line-height: 50px;
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: red;
}
#show_ads {
    width: 500px;
    height: 200px;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,.3);
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    display: none;
}
```

jQuery:

```
(function( $ ){
   $.fn.readMore = function() {
      $("#show_ads").show();
      window.setInterval(function(){
         $("#show_ads").hide();
         $(".content").height(500);
         $(".read-more").hide();
      }, 5000);
   };
})( jQuery );
```

View this in JsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/cp5rayo1/

To select an Id in jQuery that starts with a specific name, use this:

```
$('div[id^="id_here"]')
```

Comment: Joost, What i want is I have 4 different divs, when user clicks on one of each div it will automatically activated then after 3 minutes the div named as **show_ads** will appear in the current active div just for 10 seconds and close so user can continue to read the content of that activated div

Comment: I understand what you are trying to do now, I'll try to make a JSFiddle for you.

Comment: Really Thankful for you

Comment: Check this fiddle, I set the ad waiting time to 5 seconds. http://jsfiddle.net/cp5rayo1/

Answer (score 0):

Give your main divs a common class so that you can easily select them all together, e.g.:

```
<div id="main_1" class="main">
```

Then you can bind a click to them as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#show").hide();            // hide the ad to start
  $(".main").click(function() { // on click of any main div
    $("#show").stop(true,true)  // stop any previous animation
              .hide()           // hide the ad
              .appendTo(this)   // move the ad to the clicked div
              .delay(180000)    // wait 3 minutes before next animation step
              .fadeIn(10)       // fade the ad in
              .delay(10000)     // then wait 10 seconds
              .fadeOut(100);    // hide the ad
  });
});
```

Note that when you append (or `.appendTo()`) an element that already exists the element is *moved,* not copied. Full explanations of all the methods I've used may be found at [jQuery's API site](http://api.jquery.com/).

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/181b4zf7/